# How to debug a running perl process?

Tags: perl, debugging, webserver, cgi

I just started to maintain an old system that use perl as CGI scripting language.
I know I can use `perl -d programName.pl` to debug a perl script, but how to debug 
a running perl process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for any process the `strace` command to monitor system calls, e.g. for perl process too.

You can also use [Enbugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Enbugger). From the doc:

> Allows the use of the debugger at runtime regardless of whether your
>   process was started with debugging. This is useful if you would like
>   to add hooks so the debugger is loaded on some kind of event or UNIX
>   signal or if for some reason you're having difficulty running your
>   program with debugging turned on at compile time.

but honestly, never used it by myself, so can't tell you anything more about it.

Are you sure than need debug the running script?

Especially in CGI scripts (many times aren't persistent) and started with each request, it is much easier add some `debug prints` as @Josh stated above.

Or you can use many developer modules like Devel::Trace and such (check metacpan.org).

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this, in my perl scripts I do

`print STDERR "DB8 my comment";`

and then I do

`cat /var/www/log/error.log | grep DB8`

Of course, DB8 can be any string that is unique.

Comment: Thank you @Josh, I know I can log a lot to get the running status of program.But is there any way or a tool that I can attach to a running progress. Just like what gdb -p can do?